# How to specify JDBC request parameter values for OracleTypes.ARRAY in JMeter?

Tags: arrays, jdbc, request, jmeter, procedure

I need to use callable statement to call an Oracle stored procedure. The input is OracleTypes.ARRAY.  My question is, how do I specify  parameter values for this array? I've tried these formats:

- {a, b}
- [a,b]
- (a,b)

none of them work.  Unfortunately, there is no example in the documentation http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Request

I also have not found anything on the internet discussing this.

Comment: Your first way should be right, normally you'd pass the array as `{a, b}`. But I am not quite sure if array is supported at all. One thing to try though: since JMeter reads those parameters as CSV, comma likely breaks its parsing. So try to put array in quotes `"{a,b}"`, and parameter type should be `ARRAY` (no class name). If that doesn't work, you probably found a bug.

Comment: Kiril - I did put in ARRAY as the type, as specified in the javadoc http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Types.html

Comment: Did you try to put it in double quotes as I suggested?
I looked at the code, and saw nothing special for array handling, although I would expect to. So as I said, I suspect it's just not handled at the moment.

Comment: Kiril - I just tried with double quotes so the format is "{a,b}".   I got this error: "Fail to convert to internal representation: {a,b}", seems it's not able to handle array.

Comment: I suggest submitting bug with them: https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/enter_bug.cgi